# Character won't jump in Unity2D but entered the jump statement

Tags: c#, unity3d-2dtools

I have a little problem with my player control script (C#) in the unity enigne. I worked out the following script with the basic movement of the player. The problem is that the player can enter the jump statement (the debug log printed it out) 
[Debug Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUQNV.png)
but it will not work. The character is still on the ground. 
The jump function will be enabled when the player is on the ground (grounded) and did not a double jump.
So my question is are there any "code mistakes" or maybe some configuration problems which I do not see?

Thank you for your help in advance!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour
{

    // public variables
    public float speed = 3f;
    public float jumpHeight = 5f;

    // private variables
    Vector3 movement;
    Animator anim;
    Rigidbody2D playerRigidbody;

    // variables for the ground check
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    private bool grounded;
    private bool doubleJump;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Proves if the player is on the ground and activate the double jump function
        if (grounded)
        {
            doubleJump = false;
        }

        // First line of proving the jump
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && grounded)
        {
            Debug.Log("Jump if entered");
            Jump();
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !doubleJump && !grounded)
        {
            Debug.Log("double Jump");
            Jump();
            doubleJump = true;
        }


        // Flipping the Player when he runs back
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
        {
            playerRigidbody.transform.localScale = new Vector2(-1.7f, 1.7f);
        }

        else
        {
            playerRigidbody.transform.localScale = new Vector2(1.7f, 1.7f);
        }
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        // References setting up
        playerRigidbody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        // simple Movement without a speed control
        Move(horizontal, vertical);
        Animating(horizontal, vertical);

        // Section for ground detection
        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius, whatIsGround);

        // Set the parameter for the jump animation false or true
        anim.SetBool("Grounded", grounded);
    }

    void Move(float horizontal, float vertical)
    {
        movement.Set(horizontal, 0f, vertical);
        movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        playerRigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + movement);
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        playerRigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpHeight);
        // playerRigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpHeight), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        Debug.Log("Jump function");
    }

    void Animating(float h, float v)
    {
        bool walking = h != 0f || v != 0f;
        anim.SetBool("IsWalking", walking);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your object has the animation of the jump activated?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
The problem is not the animation, the character did not change the position (jump). I can deal with it when the animation not works but not with the problem that it not change the position. 
But here is another strange thing. I put this little code in the `void update()` - function: `if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            playerRigidbody.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpHeight);` and this do also not work.

Comment: If you put another animation movement with space, it works?

Also, as far i remember, in my main character object i used the 3rd person controller and jump with space was ready by itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just guessing here, but maybe Vector3.up does not work for 2D physics? I'm not really into 2D, but you could try

```
playerRigidbody.AddForce(transform.up * jumpHeight);
```

instead.

Also, have you tried different values for jumpHeight? 5 might be way to small depending on the mass you set for your rigidbody.
And make sure you haven't restricted any axes in the inspector.

Comment: OMG! @Tarrok you opened my eyes!
Yesterday I tried different settings of the jumpHeigt - all in the play mode.
Thanks for your great hints.

Comment: @t3chnico Glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Note:  If you want the object to move in a reliable predictable way but still allow physics interactions, use MovePosition (set the object to kinematic if you want it to be unaffected by physics but still be able to affect other things, and uncheck kinematic if you want both objects to be able to be acted on by physics. 

If you want to move your object but let physics handle the finer details, add a force.

playerRigidbody.rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector3.up * 10 * Time.deltaTime); 

use Vector.up, Vector.down, vector.right, Vectore.left along with time.deltaTime to have smooth movement along the frame.
```